# AngularJS - default value of select (id fields are named differently)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I have the following data (provided from an Angular service, stored in the controller) I need to use to populate a drop-down, and also select the default value. When the page renders, the first dropdown option is `"?"` and is selected by default. The second dropdown option is "Name 1".

I've read around and tried different things, so I'm wondering if this is caused the `track by` being based on an id field with a different name (id vs. otherId)? Any ideas?

For the dropdown:

```
{"someDataSet":
  [
    {"id": "1", "name": "Name 1"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "Name 2"}
  ]
}
```

For selecting the default value:

```
{"otherDataSet":
  {"otherId": "1", "otherName": "Name 1"}
}
```

My front-end code:

```
<select ng-options="someData.name for someData in controller.someDataSet
track by someData.id" ng-model="controller.otherDataSet.otherId"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle or Plunker ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution: http://codepen.io/tzach/pen/LVKeGJ

Adding an option element will set the default value until your real data is loaded:

```
<option value="{{ controller.otherDataSet.otherId }}">{{ controller.otherDataSet.otherName }}</option>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try today.